# How can I remove the child from a stack in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have been creating a WebView in Flutter. I want to show a CircularProgressIndicator as an overlay while the page loads. For this, I have used a stack where the top child is a Container with CircularProgressIndicator in Center whereas the WebView loads as the bottom child. Now I see a callback named onPageFinished in the WebView which I want to use to remove the Container on top in the Stack. I don't seem to find a way to remove a child from the stack. How do I go about implementing this?

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onPageFinished: hideLoader,
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    )
  ],
)),

void hideLoader(String url) {}
```

Comment: @SametÖZTOPRAK - please stop editing question titles from "How can I" to "How to". This is incorrect. See, for instance, [Why do my "How to" questions often get renamed to "How do I"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20730/32732) for more.

Comment: @WaiHaLee it is your perspective I do not search the question "How Can I" it is very funny, Need to more generalized question and I correct misspell as well.

Comment: You've suggested some edits which *only* wrongly changed the title to "How to", e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24933305) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24931739). As for the grammar, it's not just my opinion - see, e.g. [Can “How to” be a question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/162104/32732).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
    Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onPageFinished: hideLoader,
        ),
        this._hideLoader == true
        ? Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          )
        : Container()
      ],
    )),
  bool _hideLoader = false;
  void hideLoader(String url) {
    setState(() {
      this._hideLoader = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Of course! Works like a charm. Just a small correction. The flag should be initiated as `bool _hideLoader = true;` instead of `bool _hideLoader = false;`